# Lead Status Converted Value to Contact Status

Tags: leads, contact, lead-conversion

We have a converted Lead Status value "Sales Accepted", which we have in a custom Contact Status field on the Contact level as well. When a Lead is converted, where do the Converted values get mapped to? How can I map a Lead Status (default field) to a Contact Status (custom field).

For some reason, I believe our Org already had this mapping, which I have since proven myself wrong. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 5):

**From the docs:**

> When you convert a lead, data in standard lead fields is transferred
>   into standard account, contact, and opportunity fields. For custom
>   lead fields, the data is mapped to custom account, contact, and
>   opportunity fields as specified by your administrator.
>
> **Currently we can only map custom Lead fields with custom fields on
>   Accounts, Contacts or Opportunities objects.**
>
> If you want to map a Standard Lead field to a custom field on Accounts
>   or Contacts or Opportunities object, follow below given steps.
>
> **For Example:** How to map standard Rating field on lead record to custom
>   field on Contact object?
>
> **Step 1:** Click on Setup | Customize | Leads | Fields | Click the "New"
>   button | select Data Type: Formula | Return Type: Text Formula:
>   Text(Rating) | Save it. This custom field in Leads will get the value
>   from the standard field.
>
> **Step 2:** Click on Setup | Customize | Contacts | Fields | Click the
>   "New" button | select Data Type: Text We are creating a field in
>   contact object with same data type as the field on lead.
>
> **Step 3:** Click on Setup | Customize | Leads | Fields Click the Map Lead
>   Fields button | Map: Custom formula "Rating field" from step 1 to
>   custom Contact object "Rating field" from step 2 and click Save. With
>   the above steps we can pass value from standard Lead field to custom
>   field on Contact object.
>
> The same can be done for account and opportunity objects too

Comment: This solution might work for other lead fields, but not for the Lead Status. The conversion logic happen first, and only at the end the SF update the Lead Status to the new value. Therefore during the conversion, the status value is still Open (or something) and this value will be copied to the Contact

Answer (score 3):

If you set up custom lead fields, you specify how that custom information converts to custom fields in accounts, contacts, and opportunities.

1. From the object management settings for leads, go to the fields section, then click
   Map Lead Fields.
2. For each custom lead field, choose a custom account, contact, or opportunity field into which you want the information inserted when you convert a lead.
3. Save your work.

This will solve your problem.